# how can i migrate virtuemart from VM2 to VM3?

Tags: joomla, data-migration, virtuemart

Hello I would like to ask how is it possible to migrate VM2 to VM3. I want to update  my Joomla site from 2 to 3 and VM to be compatible.  I found only that http://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/installation-migration-upgrade/198-upgrade-virtuemart-2-to-virtuemart-3.html  please help I have many data on VM2 and I don't want to lose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve that. My pattern is mostly like this.

First attempt, update all Joomla components, install VirtueMart 3 via normal installer, install Joomla 3. If that fails:

Second attempt, use Daycounts Migrator and use a fresh J3/VM3 installation on the same server to transfer files and database with the migrator. If that fails:

Third attempt, compare the databases from first attempt or second attempt and export single db tables and import with the changed column names into VM 3 db.

Use a standard template like Protostar in the beginning, change to a new template only after everything else works.

This question is not answered in one answer here, I suggest the VirtueMart forum.

Answer (score 2):

this process should be careful, follow my procedures:

1. Go to official site [installed VM Migrator plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jmigrator/)
2. before you should do all your backup sql in VM2 and VM3 sites
3. Also what I had done is add another Database called migration_vm2 in my server, and import vm2 sql, this could be avoid the problem and you could query one of table to compare
4. And for import the users and orders list and products you should use VM Migrator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. First download the newest VM package from the official site. Note that normally it is a compressed file with core component and AIO component zipped inside, so you will have to extract these first.

Second, in your Joomla 2.5 backend, check Extension Manager > Database tab and do a fix if necessary. Do not forget to do a backup of all your site using Akeeba or similar extensions. Keeping a backup of existing orders is good practice.

Finally, using the Extension Manager installer, upload and install the VM3 core and the AIO after that. Clear cache and check database fixes again if necessary. 
Very important: clear your browser's cache to purge preloaded js files and so.

Check your VM3 frontend and backend, you should have all your items, registered shoppers, old orders and so. There can be some styling issues with new classes, also your shopper groups could be misconfigured, correct the prices to be shown... and thats it!

About the migration from J2.5 to J3, having VM3 installed has not been a problem for me so far. Always refresh your web browser cache after a migration in order to eliminate preloaded javascript files that are obsolete, otherwise you could have some problems trying to save menus, articles and so; just clear your cache again and thats it.